# How do I create a Show instance for b->a in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to construct a datatype that is essentially a binary tree whose: each node's left branch is a function that can act on the variable in each node's right branch. I'm new to Haskell, and I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way, but my current problem is that I can't figure out how to add my type to the Show typeclass. Here is my attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
-- file: TS.hs                                                                                                                                                       

data TypeSentence a = forall b. Apply (TypeSentence (b->a)) (TypeSentence b)
                    | Expr a

instance (Show a) => (Show (TypeSentence a)) where
        show (Expr x) = show x
        show (Apply x y) = (show x) ++ " " ++ (show y)

instance (Show (TypeSentence b->a)) where
    show (Expr x) = show "hello"

x = Expr 1
f = Expr (+1)
s = Apply f x
```

However, when I load this into ghci I get the following error:

```
TS.hs:9:24:                                                                                                                                                          
     Could not deduce (Show (b -> a)) from the context ()                                                                                                             
     arising from a use of `show' at TS.hs:9:24-29                                                                                                                  
      Possible fix:                                                                                                                                                    
      add (Show (b -> a)) to the context of the constructor `Apply'                                                                                                  
      or add an instance declaration for (Show (b -> a))                                                                                                             
        In the first argument of `(++)', namely `(show x)'                                                                                                               
        In the expression: (show x) ++ " " ++ (show y)                                                                                                                   
        In the definition of `show':                                                                                                                                     
           show (Apply x y) = (show x) ++ " " ++ (show y)                                                                                                               
 Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any ideas how I go about adding the Show (b->a) declaration?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to make a `Show` instance for _general functions_, how do you imagine that should work? I don't think you actually want this, either. — Anyway, first of all this tree of yours does not do what you say: `b->a` can act on a `b`, but in the other branch there's an `a`. I believe you want to put a `b` there?

Comment: yep, you're right. fixed that. I would like to define Show on a general function so that it if the function has a Show instance then it it shows that and if not it recurses in the definition until it bottoms out at primitive functions that have show instances.

Comment: Did you want to write `instance Show (TypeSentence (b->a))`? Note the brackets

Comment: `import Text.Show.Functions` gives you a `Show` instance for functions (`show _ = "<function>"`).

Comment: Now what kind of output would you like e.g. your `s = Apply (Expr(+1)) (Expr 1)` to produce?

Comment: @leftaroundabout This would be nice: `(+1) 1`

Comment: @Eyal: That's impossible, as it violates referential transparency.  Having some `f :: (a -> b) -> String` such that `f (+ 1) = "(+ 1)"` and `f $ \x -> x + 1 = "\\x -> x + 1"` would allow us to distinguish two equal functions; and function equality is undecidable, which prevents us from finding some "canonical form" to show.

Comment: If a useful `Show` instance for `(a → b)` could possibly exist, it would be in the Prelude ;)

Comment: @AntalS-Z: Perhaps you could expand? What if I don't care about the "canonical form?" All I care about is that once I've created this tree of expressions there is some way to display it.

Comment: @Eyal The language only guarantees that `(+1) x` will evaluate to the same thing as `x + 1` for any choice of `x`.  It does not guarantee anything about what the resulting value is made of.  For example, one of the things GHC will do is replace this occurrence of `(+)` with a completely different function called `plusInteger`.  It is valid to change a program this way because there's no observable difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code as written, so I'm going to go through them one by one.

1. You can't add a particularly informative instance for `Show (a -> b)`.  Consider how you'd have to write it:

   ```
   instance Show (a -> b) where
     show f = error "What goes here?"
   ```

   Since `f` is a function, there's nothing you can do with it other than apply it to a value; and since `a` is a fully-polymorphic type, you can't create a value of type `a` to apply `f` to.  So your only option is something like

   ```
   instance Show (a -> b) where
     show _ = "<function>"
   ```

   As Daniel Fischer said in a comment, this is available in the [Text.Show.Functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Show-Functions.html) module.  I wouldn't actually bother with this, though; I'd just write something like

   ```
   instance Show a => Show (TypeSentence a) where
     show (Apply _ x) = "Apply _ " ++ show x -- This still won't work; see below
     show (Expr x)    = "Expr " ++ show x
   ```

   Since `show` can only return the one string for any function, just inline that directly.
2. Even then, though, you *still* can't write that `Show` instance.  If you try to compile the instance above, you get the following error:

   ```
   TS.hs:8:36:
       Could not deduce (Show b) arising from a use of `show'
       from the context (Show a)
         bound by the instance declaration
         at TS.hs:7:10-40
       Possible fix:
         add (Show b) to the context of
           the data constructor `Apply'
           or the instance declaration
       In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show x'
       In the expression: "Apply _ " ++ show x
       In an equation for `show': show (Apply _ x) = "Apply _ " ++ show x
   ```

   The problem is that, in your definition of `TypeSentence`, `Apply` hides a variable (bound as `x` in the definition of `show`) of `TypeSentence` parametrized by some arbitrary existentially-hidden type `b`.  But there's no guarantee that `b` is showable, so `show x` won't type check, which is the error produced above: there's no instance for `Show b`, because `b` is arbitrary.  So to get rid of that, the simplest approach would be

   ```
   instance Show a => Show (TypeSentence a) where
     show (Apply _ _) = "Apply _ _"
     show (Expr x)    = "Expr " ++ show x
   ```

   And that's not particularly useful.  So maybe there's not a good `Show` instance for `TypeSentence`.  (And that's fine.  Many useful types don't have `Show` instances.)
3. This one's unrelated to everything else.  The `instance Show (TypeSentence b -> a)` declaration tries to declare an instance of `Show` for functions from `TypeSentence b` to `a`; if you reparenthesize that as `instance Show (TypeSentence (b -> a))`, you still need both the `FlexibleInstances` and `OverlappingInstances` extension to get that to compile.  So that you should probably just axe.

Comment: Is there a way to print the type? The equivilant to the GHC command :type?

Comment: Anthony: Kind of, if you change the data type.  If the `Apply` constructor takes a `Typeable b` constraint, then you can learn what `b` is at run time.

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's reason this through.  Your proposed `Show` instance's `show` method  will be called with some function `f :: b -> a`.

```
instance Show (b -> a) where
    show f = ...
```

What can your `show` method do?  Well, it must produce some `String`, but how will it do it?

Well, since the type of `f` is `b -> a`, the only thing you can do with `f` is apply it to something of type `b`.  Yet `show` has no argument of type `b`, and your `Show` class doesn't have any constants of type `b`, so the only thing that this `show` method could do with `f` is apply it to `undefined`.  Which may or may not produce an error, depending on whether `f` is strict or not—which you have no control over, and I'm sure you don't want `show` to error out on some arguments anyway.

But in any case, even if you did get a result from `f undefined`, this result it would have type `a`, and there really is nothing your definition can do with an `a` anyway, since you don't have any functions of type `a -> whatever` available. (And if you did have one, unless `whatever` was `String`, you'd still be in the same position.)

So there's nothing sensible you can do with `f`, and since you have no other arguments, this means that the only thing your method can do is return a value that doesn't depend on `f` or any other argument.  Thus, your method's return value has to be a constant, or `undefined`.  Since using `undefined` would be silly, the only sensible thing this `show` method can do is return a constant `String`:

```
instance Show (b -> a) where
    show _ = "<function>"
```

As Daniel Fischer mentions in his comment to your question, this is already available in `Text.Show.Functions`.

But the lesson here is to take this as an example on how to reason through your question.  This is one of the neat things about Haskell: you can often prove what a function can, can't or must do just by looking at the types.  For example, if you have `foo :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, assuming `foo` is not silly enough doesn't use `undefined` gratuitously, you can infer that the `b`s in the `[b]` result are obtained by applying the `a -> b` type argument to elements of the `[a]` argument.  There is no other way for `foo` to produce values of type `b`.  (If you didn't guess already, the most natural function of that type is `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the @Davorak 's comment is what you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15846061/6289448

I just share it here. Pass test in `ghc 8.6.5`.

There is a partial solution that goes beyond just a fixed string for all functions using Data.Typeable.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a->b) where
  show _ = show $ typeOf (undefined :: a -> b)
```

in ghci

```
> let test :: Int->Int; test x = x + x
> test
Int -> Int
```

Unfortunately without a type signature the type will go to it default.

```
> let test x = x + x
> test
Integer -> Integer
```

This solution works on multiple function arities because a -> b -> c is the same as a -> (b -> c) which you might as well write as a -> d where d = b -> c.

```
> let m10 a b c d e f g h i j = a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h* i * j
> m10
Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
        -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

This method does not work however when it is unknown if parameters of the function have the typeable class however so while map (+1) will work map will not.

```
> map (+1)
[Integer] -> [Integer]
> map

<interactive>:233:1:
...
```

After glancing at the internals of Data.Data and an experiment or two it seems like it could be refactored to be a little more generalized cover more functions.

---

---

If you dont like implemention above, just implement it by yourself!
(Let me know If there's a better way, please!)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

newtype GenType a =
    GenType
        { asTypeStr :: String
        }

class GenTypeArbitrary a where
    gtArbitrary :: a -> GenType a

instance GenTypeArbitrary String where
    gtArbitrary :: String -> GenType String
    gtArbitrary _ = GenType "String123"

instance GenTypeArbitrary Bool where
    gtArbitrary :: Bool -> GenType Bool
    gtArbitrary _ = GenType "Bool123"

instance GenTypeArbitrary Int where
    gtArbitrary :: Int -> GenType Int
    gtArbitrary _ = GenType "Int123"

instance (GenTypeArbitrary a, GenTypeArbitrary b) => GenTypeArbitrary (a -> b) where
    gtArbitrary :: (GenTypeArbitrary a, GenTypeArbitrary b) => (a -> b) -> GenType (a -> b)
    gtArbitrary _ = GenType $ aTypeStr' ++ " --> " ++ bTypeStr
      where
        aTypeStr = asTypeStr (gtArbitrary (undefined :: a))
        aTypeStr' =
            if "-->" `isInfixOf` aTypeStr
                then "(" ++ aTypeStr ++ ")"
                else aTypeStr
        bTypeStr = asTypeStr (gtArbitrary (undefined :: b))

instance  (GenTypeArbitrary a, GenTypeArbitrary b) => Show (a -> b) where
  show f = asTypeStr $ gtArbitrary f

test1 :: Int -> String
test1 x = ""

test2 :: Int -> String -> Int -> Bool -> Bool
test2 _ _ _ _ = False

test3 :: Int -> ((String -> Int) -> Bool) -> Bool
test3 _ _ = False

test4 :: Int -> (Bool -> (String -> Int)) -> Bool
test4 _ _ = False
```

```sh
λ > show  (test4)
    "Int123 --> (Bool123 --> String123 --> Int123) --> Bool123"
it :: String


...


λ > show  (test3)
    "Int123 --> ((String123 --> Int123) --> Bool123) --> Bool123"
it :: String
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function's domain is a finite set then you can print the value of your function at all the points. In Haskell you can do that with the typeclasses `Ix` and `Bounded` by using a function like:

```
rangeF :: (Ix a, Bounded a) => [a]
rangeF = range (minBound, maxBound)
```

Comment: You could also use `Enum a` instead of `Ix a`, and use `[minBound..maxBound]` (equivalently, `enumFromTo minBound maxBound`).