# Partial application of data constructor

Tags: haskell, currying, partial-application

I don't understand why the following exercise "works" in *Haskell Programming from First Principles*:

```
type Subject = String
type Verb = String
type Object = String

data Sentence =
    Sentence Subject Verb Object
    deriving (Eq, Show)

s1 = Sentence "dogs" "drool"
s2 = Sentence "Julie" "loves" "dogs"
```

Loading this into ghci shows that it typechecks just fine, but why is it that the definition of `s1` even makes sense? I'm still very new to Haskell, so at first I thought this was because in `s1` Haskell was implicitly letting the `Object` string be empty. But then...

```
*Main> s1

<interactive>:13:1:
    No instance for (Show (Object -> Sentence))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (Object -> Sentence))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I'm still learning how to properly interpret these error messages, so please bear with me. But can someone explain what `No instance for (Show (Object -> Sentence))` means? More specifically, how does leaving out the `Object` string in `s1` result in this `(Object -> Sentence)` thing?

I'm sure this is stupid easy, but I don't think the book has equipped me to understand this by this point...

Comment: Look up function currying and keep in mind that data constructors like `Sentence` are treated pretty much like regular functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but why is it that the definition of `s1` even makes sense?

As @Alec mentioned, it's called currying. One way to see what is going on is to have GHCI tell you what the type of `s1` is:

```
ghci> :t s1
s1 :: Object -> Sentence
```

So `s1` is a function taking an `Object` to a `Sentence`. Another way to think about is to start with the definition:

```
s1 = Sentence "dogs" "drool"
```

and using equational reasoning apply both sides to a value `x`:

```
s1 x = Sentence "dogs" "drool" x
```

So when you call `s1 x` it's the same as calling `Sentence` with the first two function arguments hard-coded to `"dogs"` and `"drool"`, and `x` becomes the third argument to the `Sentence` function.

> can someone explain what "No instance for `(Show (Object -> Sentence))`" means?

When you evaluate something in GHCI is it basically the same as asking Haskell to `print` it. That is,

```
ghci> 3+4
```

is effectively the same as:

```
ghci> print (3+4)
```

(This rule doesn't apply to IO-actions like `getLine` or even `print` itself. In those cases Haskell just runs the IO-action.)

In order to `print` something there has to be a Show instance for the type.
But as we've seen above, `s1` is a function of type `Object -> Sentence`, and there are no predefined Show instances for functions.

Note that there is a Show instance for `Sentence` values because you asked GHC to derive one with `deriving (Eq, Show)`. So when you type at the GHCI prompt:

```
ghci> Sentence "Julie" "loves" "dogs"
```

you get back:

```
Sentence "Julie" "loves" "dogs"
```

because you are really asking GHCI to run `print (Sentence "Julie" "loves" "dogs")`.

Note that `print` itself is defined as [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#print):

```
print x = putStrLn (show x)
```

and the call to `show` is the reason why a value needs to have a Show instance defined for it in order to print it.

Comment: You can also use `:t Sentence` to see that the constructor has type `Subject -> Verb -> Object -> Sentence`; `:t Sentence "dogs"` has type `Object -> Verb -> Sentence`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> No instance for (Show (Object -> Sentence))
>   arising from a use of `print'
> Possible fix:
>   add an instance declaration for (Show (Object -> Sentence))
> In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
> ```

To supplement @ErikR's answer: you may be wondering why GHC doesn't have a built-in support for displaying functions, i.e. unlike integers and strings, functions don't have an instance for the `Show` typeclass (these terms will be explained in depth later in the book, so don't worry if you don't understand what's a typeclass and an instance), unless you explicitly define it yourself. As someone who is learning Haskell and comes from an Object-Oriented background, I found it easier to get an intuition for typeclasses by thinking of them as Java-like interfaces.

So, why there's no `Show` insance for functions? The [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions) provides two answers:

1.Practically, GHC doesn't keep track of variable names, i.e. the following are the same for the compiler:

```
addOne num = num + 1
f x = x + 1
f y = y + 1
```

Additionally, functions can be optimized, e.g. the following may have equivalent representations

```
f x = x - x + x
f x = x
```

2.Theoretically, a function is defined by its graph, i.e. the set of (input, output) pairs. e.g. for

```
f x = x + x
```

the pairs are (1,2), (2,4), etc.
Thus, functions with the same graph are identical GHC-wise, e.g

```
f x = x + x
g y = 2 * y
```

but you would expect `show f` and `show g` to be different, especially if you use significant variable names instead of x and y.

That said, you can use a pragma (an extension for the GHC compiler, that contains some functionality beyond the Haskell language standard) that would show only the function's type, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15846061/165753):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a->b) where
  show _ = show $ typeOf (undefined :: a -> b)
```

This will get you

```
> s1
[Char] -> Sentence
```

since `Object` is an alias of `String` (using the `type` keyword, `String` is itself an alias for `[Char]`).
If you want to explicitly see the distinction between subjects and objects, you can convert `Object` to a type with a datatype constructor `MkObject`:

```
newtype Object = MkObject String deriving (Eq, Show)

s1 = Sentence "dogs" "drool"
s2 = Sentence "Julie" "loves" (MkObject "dogs")
```

and voilà

```
> s1
Object -> Sentence
```